# django-query: get parent value based on children field

Tags: django, django-queryset

I am sorry if I am not very clear with the query I am trying to build, based on the following models:

```
class BankingDetail(models.Model):
    sfAttachmentID = models.CharField(max_length=18, unique = True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
class TransactionBankDetail(models.Model):
    bankingDetail = models.ForeignKey(BankingDetail, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='BankingDetails')
    institution = models.TextField(blank=True, unique = False, null=True)
```

I am trying to find which institutions I have and how many are they. However, because 1 BankingDetail can have multiple TransactionBankDetail, I want to count this values only once. In other words, based in my query:

```
#institution_by_attachments = TransactionBankDetail.objects.filter(institution__isnull=False).values('bankingDetail__sfAttachmentID', 'institution').annotate(total=1).order_by('total').reverse()

institution_by_attachments = TransactionBankDetail.objects.filter(institution__isnull=False).values('bankingDetail__sfAttachmentID', 'institution')
for i in institution_by_attachments:
    print(i)
```

my result will look like

```
    {'bankingDetail__sfAttachmentID': '0067F0000bCRuSx', 'institution': 'Atlantic'}
    {'bankingDetail__sfAttachmentID': '0067F0000bCRuSx', 'institution': 'Atlantic'}
    {'bankingDetail__sfAttachmentID': '0067F0000bCRuSx', 'institution': 'Atlantic'}
    {'bankingDetail__sfAttachmentID': '0067F0000bCRuSx', 'institution': 'Atlantic'}
    {'bankingDetail__sfAttachmentID': 'Ost89Porque-111', 'institution': 'Atlantic'}
    {'bankingDetail__sfAttachmentID': '0060p000008ieSm', 'institution': 'South Pacific'}
    {'bankingDetail__sfAttachmentID': '0060p000008ieSm', 'institution': 'South Pacific'}
    {'bankingDetail__sfAttachmentID': '0060p000008ieSm', 'institution': 'South Pacific'}
    {'bankingDetail__sfAttachmentID': '0060p000008ieSm', 'institution': 'South Pacific'}
    {'bankingDetail__sfAttachmentID': '0060p000008ieSm', 'institution': 'South Pacific'}
    {'bankingDetail__sfAttachmentID': '0060p000008lpYC', 'institution': 'Africa'}
    {'bankingDetail__sfAttachmentID': '0060p000008lpYC', 'institution': 'Africa'}
    {'bankingDetail__sfAttachmentID': '0060p000008lpYC', 'institution': 'Africa'}
    {'bankingDetail__sfAttachmentID': '12365478987test123', 'institution': 'South Pacific'}
    {'bankingDetail__sfAttachmentID': '12365478987test123', 'institution': 'South Pacific'}
    {'bankingDetail__sfAttachmentID': '12365478987test123', 'institution': 'South Pacific'}
```

If i use this for my aggregate I will be getting the wrong results:

```
Atlantic        5
South Pacific   8
Africa          3
```

What I want is:

```
South Pacific   2
Atlantic        2
Africa          1
```

Comment: I guess you could use `distinct()` at first and after that `annotate(Count('institution')`. I dont understand your issue in detail. Would you like to eliminate duplicats e.g. `'bankingDetail__sfAttachmentID'` and only get the amount of different `BankingDetails`-relations ? [distinct](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) and [count](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate)

Comment: @KlimBim yes I want to delete the duplicates, the current query dumps Atlantic 5, the last table is my desire result, Atlantic should be 2, becuase from the 5 records they are only 2 unique ID's for bankingDetail__sfAttachmentID, I think in the ideal world institution should have been in the BankingDetail not in TransactionBankDetail, but that is how i received the data and now is a bit late/hard to change this